# Make a 1x8 cell in ncurses without border

Tags: c++, ncurses

I want to make a 1x8 cell in ncurses without border. The first thing I did is making a window

```
WINDOW*win = newwin(height, width, 0, 0);
```

with height 24 and width 80. I want to make a column header and a row header.In the column I want strings 'A' to 'I' and in the rowheader I want strings '1' to '23'. This means that all cells are height 1 and width 8 and there is on position (0,0) an empty cell. I want every cell in the header with the property `STANDOUT`. So I wrote a function `DrawCell()`. This is what I tried

```
void DrawCell(int x , int y, const char* ch){
   clear();
   wattron(win, A_STANDOUT);
   mvwprintw(win, x,y,ch);
   wrefresh(win);
   getchar(); 
   endwin();
}//DrawCell
```

The problem is that this function only display the string 'ch' in `STANDOUT`. But I cant figure out how to place this string in a cell with height 1 and width 8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the description, it sounds as if you want something like

```
#define CELL_WIDE 8
#define CELL_HIGH 1

void DrawCell(int col , int row, const char* ch) {
   int y = row * CELL_HIGH;
   int x = col * CELL_WIDE;
   wattron(win, A_STANDOUT);
   wmove(win, y, x);                 // tidier to be separate...
   wprintw("%*s", " ");              // fill the cell with blanks
   wprintw("%.*s", CELL_WIDE, ch);   // write new text in the cell
   wrefresh(win);
#if 0
   getchar(); 
   endwin();
#endif
}//DrawCell
```

because you have to translate the cell's row and column position into x and y coordinates.

A few notes:

- I ifdef'd out the call to `getchar` because that appears to be something you used for debugging.
- If you are drawing a lot of cells, you should also move the `wrefresh(win)` out of this function, e.g., to where you refresh the whole window.
- To avoid clearing the window, you should use `wgetch(win)` rather than `getch()`, since the latter refreshes `stdscr`, and it may overwrite your window.

Addressing comment, if the function is changed to

```
void DrawCell(int col , int row, const char* ch) {
   int y = row * CELL_HIGH;
   int x = col * CELL_WIDE;
   wmove(win, y, x);                 // tidier to be separate...
   wprintw("%*s", " ");              // fill the cell with blanks
   wattron(win, A_STANDOUT);
   wprintw("%.*s", CELL_WIDE, ch);   // write new text in the cell
   wattroff(win, A_STANDOUT);
   wrefresh(win);
#if 0
   getchar(); 
   endwin();
#endif
}//DrawCell
```

then only the text of the cell is shown in standout mode.

Comment: If I run your code my whole window is STANDOUT expect the first half of the first line in the window. What I want is that DrawCell() makes a cell of height 1 and width 8 where a string can be placed in.

Comment: I had thought you wanted the entire cell to be standout.  To just make the text in each cell standout, move the  wattron call past the first printw.  In either case, the question says the cells have no border (which would make the whole screen covered with text).

Comment: I want the 1x8 cell to be STANDOUT not the whole window except the cell. If I move the wattron call I only print the cursor.